# Mathematically correct way to show that $\lim_{z\rightarrow0} f(z)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

In the book "Introduction to Complex Analysis" by H.A. Priestley, the definition of a limit $\lim_{z\rightarrow a}f(z)=w$ is that

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\forall \varepsilon>0 \exists \delta>0: 0<|z-a|<\delta \Longrightarrow|f(z)-w|<\varepsilon
\end{equation}

In exercise 3.11, the reader is asked to prove that the $\lim_{z\rightarrow0} f(z)$ exists and equals $0$ for the following:
$$(i)\ z+|z|^{3},\quad
(ii) \frac{|z|^{2}}{z},\quad
(iii)\ \frac{(\operatorname{Re} z)(\operatorname{Im} z)}{|z|}$$
For $(ii)$ it is quite obvious that if we choose $\delta=\varepsilon$ then the condition in eq. $(1)$ is satisfied. However, I am not sure how to prove $(i)$ and $(iii)$.

Comment: Hint: there's nothing wrong with choosing $\delta$ smaller than necessary. You can do things like $\delta=\min(\frac12,\varepsilon^4)$.

Comment: @Karl, I thought I might be missing some theorem/trick since I couldn't find a more obvious choice for $\delta$. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (i), note that $|z + |z|^3| \le |z| + |z|^3 = \delta + \delta^3$. If $\delta < 1$ (you are free to choose $\delta$ satisfying this extra condition) then this can be bounded by $2\delta$.

For (iii), note that $\left|\frac{(\Re z)(\Im z)}{|z|}\right|
= \frac{|\Re z| |\Im z|}{|z|} \le \frac{|z|^2}{|z|}$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Great, I get it now. Thank you :)